# Hide a <td> behind another <td> inside a <table>

Tags: html, css

I have a table which looks something like the following.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="selected plus"><a>+</a></td>
        <td><a class="minus">-</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want that only the selected `td` is visible. My restrictions are to achieve this only through `CSS`. I am not able to alter the `HTML` or inject some kind of `JavaScript`.

This is what I come up with yet:

- position the selected `td` over the other
- expand the selected `td` to "displace" the other
- hide the not selected `td`

Unfortunately I was not successful with neither of those ideas, so do you guys have any idea how to achieve this?

Here is a jsfiddle to play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/u6n7r/6/

I would be happy with a cross browser solution, but IE9 support is mandatory.

Comment: Wow you guys are great, thanks. There are cool solutions, that will work for me. But I will still wait till tomorrow before accepting, to give other Ideas a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hide the `<td/>` with `display: none`:

```
td:not(.selected) { display: none; }
```

Here is an [Update to your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6n7r/8/)

Comment: Gah, beat me to it by seconds!

Comment: @evilscary, guess how often I had to say the same to myself. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Position the table relative. Position the td's absolute, with top:0 and left: 0. Give the td's a z-index of 10. Give .selected a z-index of 11.

```
.selected {
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 11;
}

.plus {

}

.minus {

}

td {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 3px solid red;
    background-color: silver;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
table {
    border: 3px solid blue;
    width: 72px;
    height: 36px;
    position: relative;
}
```